# Welcher Tag passt zu einer "Wie verbreitet ist Wort X"-Frage?

Tags: support

[Diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/50694/15277), die danach fragt, wie verbreitet/bekannt das Wort "Treppenwitz" ist, hat (nur) den Tag `compounds`, der hier natürlich überhaupt nicht passt. Ich habe aber keinen gefunden, der eher passen würde. (`Vocabulary` oder das Synonym `Wortschatz` wäre eine Möglichkeit, aber da steht explizit: "do not use for questions about specific words.") Gibt es einen passenden Tag oder sollte man einen einführen?

Comment: If we want to introduce a new tag we need to make sure it is of value. That means a lot of question could be tagged with it. If anybody suggests such a tag here it may be a good idea to also tell us what this new tag would be used for.

Comment: Etymology - ich habe das mal hinzugefügt. Wahrscheinlich sind ziemlich viele compound Fragen etymologisch. ;-)

Comment: @Takkat Meinst du das allgemein, daß ein neuer Tag hilfreich ist, oder meinst du diese spezielle Frage verdient einen neuen Tag?

Comment: @Thomas: das muss die Community entscheiden, aber ich meine, dass einen Tag speziell für nur eine Frage keine besonders gute Idee ist, solange man nicht weiß, wofür man ihn sonst noch brauchen könnte.

Comment: @Takkat Ich wäre ja hier dafür den Tag `vocabulary` zu verwenden. Da wird zwar nach einem einzelnen Wort gefragt, aber es geht hier ja nicht um eine Übersetzung, sondern darum, wie weit sich das Wort überhaupt im Vokabular von deutschen Sprechern befindet. Aber Fragen wie "benützt eigentlich irgendwer das Wort X?" sollten sich ja noch mehr finden lassen, hätte ich gedacht.

Comment: @sgf: man könnte z.B. `word-usage` nehmen, oder einen neuen Tag `word-frequency` generieren, der dann das träfe, was du meinst.